# preg_replace() digits to an array item

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I've got this array:

```
<?php

    $menu = array(
        9 => 'pages/contact/',
        10 => 'pages/calender/jan/'
        //...
    );

?>
```

And I've got a string that looks like this:

```
$string = "This is a text with a <a href="###9###">link</a> inside it.";
```

I want to replace `###9###` with `pages/contact/`.

I've got this:

```
$string = preg_replace("/###[0-9]+###/", "???", $string);
```

But I can't use `$menu[\\\1]`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php), where you can apply a callback function fore each match, e.g.

```
$string = preg_replace_callback("/###(\d+)###/", function($m)use($menu){
    if(isset($menu[$m[1]]))
        return $menu[$m[1]];
    return "default";
}, $string);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a solution with `preg_replace_callback` but you can build an array where searched strings are associated to their replacement strings and then use `strtr`:

```
$menu = array(
9 => 'pages/contact/',
10 => 'pages/calender/jan/'
.... );

$keys = array_map(function ($i) { return "###$i###"; }, array_keys($menu));
$rep = array_combine($keys, $menu);

$result = strtr($string, $rep);
```